# How to implement sso using Django-mama-cas and Django-cas-ng

Tags: django, python-3.x, single-sign-on

I want to develop something in Django where 2 applications( app1 , app2) will be at 1 server and an another server for 1 another application(app3).

```
app1 is for user authentication.
app2 is for main site.
app3 is for chat.
```

for app2 and app3 I want authentication from app1.
So I was thinking about implementing sso.
After searching I came to know about [django-mama-cas](https://github.com/jbittel/django-mama-cas), [django-cas-ng](https://github.com/mingchen/django-cas-ng).
But I am in confusion about concept and implementation using those CAS mentioned above.
Guide me with example(settings.py, urls.py) to implement/solve my problem.